# Dividing a network into 4 subnets - stuck

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

An ISP has provided your company with the /25 network 198.118.133.0. Divide this into four (4) subnets.

Complete the following table; both Network addresses and Broadcast addresses should be in dotted-decimal notation.

Assume the all zero's and all one's subnets are usable.

I am unsure if what I am doing is correct as I thought a /25 could only be divided into 2 subnets, therefore would a /26 network be needed

This is what I have:
Subnets(4) 
192.111.133.0. 
192.111.133.64 
192.111.133.128 
192.111.133.192

Broadcasts
192.111.133.63
192.111.133.127
192.111.133.191
192.111.133.255

There is no way for me to check my answer so I cant check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following address: `198.118.133.0`

And you need to divide a `/25` network into 4 subnets. That means you only have 128 available hosts. So what you need to do is:

Divide 128 by 4 and you'll have a 32 hosts subnet.

So the division will be:

```
198.118.113.0 - 198.118.113.31

198.118.113.32 - 198.118.113.63

198.118.113.64 - 198.118.113.95

198.118.113.96 - 198.118.113.127
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Would the subnet mask then be 255.255.255.128

Comment: Yes, it would be that for the /25. But each one of these subnets would have a different mask.